# Getting 404 from inversify-express-utils controller

Tags: typescript, express, inversifyjs

I'm struggling to get an inversify-express-utils service properly configured. I'm trying to use two controllers, but only one of them seems to be discovered by inversify.

With my current configuration, only `helloController` seems to be registering. Requests to `GET .../api/v1/hello` respond as expected with 200 OK. However, requests to `GET .../api/health` respond with 404 NOT FOUND.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my current configuration:

```
src
│
└──api
   │  index.ts
   │
   └──controller
      │  index.ts
      │  healthController.ts
      │
      └──v1
         │  index.ts
         │  helloController.ts
```

**src/api/index.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import {Container} from "inversify"
import {InversifyExpressServer} from "inversify-express-utils"
import "./api/controller"

const inversifyContainer = new Container()
const server = new InversifyExpressServer(inversifyContainer)
const serverInstance = server.build()
serverInstance.listen(3000)
```

**src/api/controller/index.ts**

```
export * from "./healthController"
export * from "./v1/"
```

**src/api/controller/healthController.ts**

```
import {Request, Response} from "express"
import {BaseHttpController, controller, httpGet} from "inversify-express-utils"

@controller('/')
export class HealthController extends BaseHttpController {

    constructor(){ super() }

    @httpGet('/health')
    private health(req: Request, resp: Response) {
        resp.json({uptime: process.uptime()})
    }
}
```

**src/api/controller/v1/index.ts**

```
export * from "./helloController"
```

**src/api/controller/v1/helloController.ts**

```
import {Request, Response} from "express"
import {BaseHttpController, controller, httpGet} from "inversify-express-utils"


@controller('/v1/hello')
export class helloController extends BaseHttpController {

    @httpGet('/')
    private hello(req: Request, resp: Response) {
        resp.send("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The @controller() annotation doesn't seem to work with a root ('/') path.

Works after changing **healthController.ts** to the following

```
import {Request, Response} from "express"
import {BaseHttpController, controller, httpGet} from "inversify-express-utils"

@controller('/health')
export class HealthController extends BaseHttpController {

    @httpGet('/')
    private health(req: Request, resp: Response) {
        resp.json({uptime: process.uptime()})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well, but you shouldn't use a slash as a root path:

```
import {Request, Response} from "express"
import {BaseHttpController, controller, httpGet} from "inversify-express-utils"

@controller('')
export class HealthController extends BaseHttpController {

    @httpGet('/health')
    private health(req: Request, resp: Response) {
        resp.json({uptime: process.uptime()})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added the done controller binding in your inversify container.
So it would look like the following:

```
 const container = new container();

`container.bind<Controller>(TYPES.Controller).to(Controller)`
```

This will ensure that you don't get 404 not found and your controller is correctly registered(bound) in your inversify container